# react js multiple input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to build form inputs in reactjs. the code below works for just one form inputs.

Now I want to add two more form inputs as per

```
Firstname <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
Lastname <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
```

below is the working code that I want to implement the two form inputs above.
source

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to manage forms in React is to make sure each of your `<input>` tags has a `name` value.  Then ensure that your component's state has fields for each input that matches the `name` exactly.

In your `onChange` handler, you can then say:

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
```

This will update the state with change to any of the inputs, and apply the change to that specific state value.

Then for `handleSubmit`, you send those values from state to where ever you need to process the form information.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
handleChange(event){
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
  }
```